# Popup challenge like browser for didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am utilizing self-signed certificate, and I want to popup the message same as the safari does as if the cert is not signed by Trusted CA's, the user accepts or cancel to go forward. I am not sure as of how to utilize this through didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge. I noticed when didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge fails, it gives an error which have that prompt in local description, but there is no content in the array, to satisfy same behavior as it does when using webview or safari.

Any input in this consideration will be helpful

Thanks.